# PHP day of week numeric to day of week text

Tags: php, date

This may be really easy but I can't find a PHP function to do this...

OK so

```
$dow_numeric = date('w');
```

gives the numeric day of the week 0-6 for Sunday to Saturday.

And

```
$dow_text = date('D');
```

gives the 3 letter abbreviation for the text day of the week (Sun, Mon, etc.)

Is there a function or easy way to use `$dow_numeric` to get `$dow_text`?  If I have '0' as `$dow_numeric`, how can I make `$dow_text = 'Sun'`?  Yes a `switch` statement could do the job, but I’m looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Create an array to map numeric DOWs to text DOWs.

```
$dowMap = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
```

If you need locale support, load the dow of some random date (epoch (0) would be a good date for example) and then for the next 6 days and build the dow map dynamically.

Comment: Super easy and agree...  so I take it there isn't a function already though.

Comment: Clever hack that reinvents the wheel :)

Answer (score 141):

Bit of a hack, but:

```
$dow_text = date('D', strtotime("Sunday +{$dow_numeric} days"));
```

Comment: It's not hacky, it's slick! ;-)

Comment: Alternatively, use `date('l')` (lowercase *L*) for a full day name. [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters)

Comment: Great! But what are the {} for?

Comment: @GDY Its called [complex (curly) syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: @aProgger thanks didnt know that this is called like that. But in this example the brackets arent necessary are they?

Comment: @GDY In this example: No they are not. One could say, its for readability. But even that is a matter of taste. In our company, we would write: strtotime('Sunday +' . $dow_numeric . ' days'). Even the ones with less PHP experience understand this.

Answer (score 75):

It's not popular, but there's actually a function [`jddayofweek`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php) for this in PHP. You can call it with the second parameter as 1 to get full gregorian week day name or 2 for the abbreviated name.

```
e.g. jddayofweek(2, 2); #returns Wed
```

Note that for this function, numbers start at Monday. So Monday=0, Tuesday=1, ...

Comment: The default start of the week is Monday. So if your Sunday == 0, everything is off by a day. Keep that in mind.

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: Why isn't it popular ?

Comment: php.net says `0=Sunday`

Comment: Julian day 0 = January 1, 4713BC (a Monday). That's why 0 = Monday; 1 = Tuesday etc. If you want to have 0 -> Sunday (etc) then you should use jddayofweek($dow_numeric - 1, 2); (or , 1 for long day names)

Comment: Think it`s less popular because the result is english, not localized?!

Comment: @klawipo, no - http://php.net/manual/en/function.jdtofrench.php (and others, see php.net....) - I believe "popular' in the answer means "not as well known" - certainly it was a new function for me (and I've been using PHP for 25+ years!)

Comment: Sadly it does not respect the current locale set with `setlocale()`.

Comment: I would recommend using the provided built in constants `CAL_DOW_SHORT` and `CAL_DOW_LONG` with `jddayofweek`. Constants definitions are less likely to change than their values.

Answer (score 9):

To get **Sunday to Saturday** from numeric day of the week **0 to 6**:

```
//For example, our target numeric day is 0 (Sunday):
$numericDay = 0; //assuming current date('w')==0 and date('D')=='Sun';
```

***Solution-1:*** Using PHP's built-in function  [jddayofweek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php) which starts from `Monday` whereas `date('w')` starts from `Sunday`:

```
jddayofweek($numericDay-1, 1); //returns 'Sun', here decreasing by '-1' is important(!)

//jddayofweek(0, 1); //returns 'Mon';
//jddayofweek(0, 2); //returns 'Monday';
```

***Solution-2:*** Using a trick(!):

```
date('D', strtotime("Sunday +{$numericDay} days")); //returns 'Sun';

//date('l', strtotime("Sunday +{$numericDay} days")); //returns 'Sunday';
```

Comment: Great idea with `strtotime`!

Comment: Great idea, yes... but someone came up with this idea 6 years before. So it was'nt his idea, more copy paste.

Comment: Thanks @Dwza, I respect your comment. But I like copy-paste if that solves our purposes and saves time. Also StackOverflow likes direct solution instead of providing just any external links.

Comment: Of course c&p is a way. But not if its in the same question. If you look carefull, the answer with the most votes contains the same solution. Just 6 years earlier. So this isnt an external link :D (only talking about the second solution) So I do get your point, but this does'nt suites to this situation :) did not wanted to force you in any kind :D

Answer (score 5):

```
function getDay(){
    $dowMap = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    $dow_numeric = date('w');
    return $dowMap[$dow_numeric];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need locale support you can use a bit improved function of [Hamishs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4742382/1990745):

Example using german weekdays:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
$dow_numeric = 3;
$dow_text = strftime('%A', strtotime("Sunday +{$dow_numeric} days"));
```

http://php.net/strftime

If `$dow_numeric` start on `0` (`0` = Monday) you can just change `Sunday` to `Monday` or
add `$dow_numeric += 1`

Comment: For those who don't like text translations, the epoch starts on Thursday, and there are 86400 seconds in a day, so strftime('%A', 86400 * ($dow_numeric + 3)) will also work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$dow_numeric = 3;

$last_sunday = strtotime('last Sunday');
$dow_text = date('D', strtotime('+'.$dow_numeric.' day', $last_sunday));
```

Answer (score 0):

For an object oriented approach you can use `DateTime('Sunday')::add()` with a `DateInterval` of `"PxD"`

When using the standard Numeric representation of the day of the week `DateTime::format('w')` as `0-6` for Sun-Sat or ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week `DateTime::format('N')` as `1-7` for Mon-Sun.
https://3v4l.org/3uthm

```
$weekday = (new DateTime('Sunday'))
    ->add(new DateInterval('P' . $dow . 'D'));
```

The ISO-8601 representation works as expected since it uses `Sunday + 7 days  (Sunday)`, resulting in `Sunday + 1 day (Monday)` and `Sunday + 6 days (Saturday)`.

Alternatively replace Sunday for Monday and use `$dowISO - 1` 
https://3v4l.org/5uLOL

```
$weekdayISO = (new DateTime('Monday'))
    ->add(new DateInterval('P' . ($dowISO - 1) . 'D'));
```

### DatePeriod Example

https://3v4l.org/uG9NT

```
$sunday = new DateTimeImmutable('Sunday');
$monday = new DateTimeImmutable('Monday');
foreach (new DatePeriod($sunday, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6) as $date) {
    $dow = $date->format('w');
    $weekday = $sunday->add(new DateInterval('P' . $dow . 'D'));

    $dowISO = $date->format('N');
    $weekdayISOM = $monday->add(new DateInterval('P' . ($dowISO - 1) . 'D'));
    $weekdayISOS = $sunday->add(new DateInterval('P' . $dowISO . 'D'));

    printf("STD:  %s = %s\nISOM: %s = %s\nISOS: %s = %s\n\n", 
        $dow, $weekday->format('l'), 
        $dowISO, $weekdayISOM->format('l'), 
        $dowISO, $weekdayISOS->format('l')
    );
}
```

**Results**

```
STD:  0 = Sunday
ISOM: 7 = Sunday
ISOS: 7 = Sunday

STD:  1 = Monday
ISOM: 1 = Monday
ISOS: 1 = Monday

STD:  2 = Tuesday
ISOM: 2 = Tuesday
ISOS: 2 = Tuesday

STD:  3 = Wednesday
ISOM: 3 = Wednesday
ISOS: 3 = Wednesday

STD:  4 = Thursday
ISOM: 4 = Thursday
ISOS: 4 = Thursday

STD:  5 = Friday
ISOM: 5 = Friday
ISOS: 5 = Friday

STD:  6 = Saturday
ISOM: 6 = Saturday
ISOS: 6 = Saturday
```