# how to format an integer into the name of a weekday in php

Tags: php, date

Is there a way to use `DateTime::CreateFromFormat` to convert a 0-6 integer into the name of a day of the week?

I am creating a calendar for a script and would like to let users customize the way the days of the week display (*Mon vs Monday*) so using an array of the week day names is not desirable.

How can I use **CreateFromFormat** to do this?

Comment: I don't think `DateTime::CreateFromFormat` will convert an integer to a day of the week. However it should work with both "Mon" and "Monday". Here is another post with suggesting more alternate functions to do something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961793/day-of-the-week-to-day-number-monday-1-tuesday-2

Comment: You mean something [like this](https://eval.in/319675) using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4742382/2812842)?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Get timestamp of first day of week +X (our integer) days.

```
// assuming monday = 0, sunday = 6
$day = 2; // our integer (wednesday)

// get timestamp of most recent monday +X days
$ts = (date('N') == 1) ? strtotime("today +$day days") : strtotime("last monday +$day days");
```

Step 2:

Print the short & long names of the weekday.

```
echo date('l', $ts); // Wednesday
echo date('D', $ts); // Wed
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question.

```
$day = 0;
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $day . '-Feb-2010');
echo $date->format('l');
```

would output :

```
Sunday
```